# How do I get the server ip/port for a ktor service?

Tags: ktor

I'm looking to write a Ktor feature that should announce the service on a local network using DNS-SD/mDNS. I would like to be able to automatically start the announcing on ktor application start and stop it on ktor application stopped. I've written code that does this using `ApplicationStarted` and `ApplicationStopped` event. This code works.

However, I can find no way of getting what IP address/port from ktor other than reading the configuration.

Is there any way of listening for/listing the connectors that ktor is currently using?

Answer (score 6):

You can access `connectors` through the `BaseApplicationEngine` instance:

```kotlin
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, 9091) {}
println(server.environment.connectors)
```

or by casting `environment` to `ApplicationEngineEnvironment`:

```kotlin
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    (environment as ApplicationEngineEnvironment).connectors.forEach { connector ->
        println("${connector.host}:${connector.port}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas, it does not work for `-port=0` configuration../